# How does URL's resourceValues(forKeys: [.typeIdentifierKey]) determine the UTI?

Tags: cocoa, nsurl, uti, foundationkit

I've got a `URL`, and I'm calling `resourceValues(forKeys: [.typeIdentifierKey])` on it, to find out the UTIs it conforms to.  Works great.

Does this method simply check whether it's a directory (like with `stat(2)`, to report "public.folder"), and if it's not a directory, the filename extension (and if none, then just "public.data", "public.item")?

That seems to be the case, but I can't find any documentation that says for sure how it determines the type.

Rationale: I've got a bunch of URLs whose UTIs I want to check against a known value, and I know they're not folders, so I could save a ton of I/O calls if I were sure that that's all that this method is doing.

UPDATE: I looked in swift-corelibs-foundation/URL.swift, but it just passes through to the NSURL method of the same name.  The swift-corelibs-foundation/NSURL.swift method just throws NSUnimplemented().   I tried looking in CFLite, which has an implementation of CFURL, but I can't seem to find anything there related to UTIs.  AFAICT, there's no open-source implementation of this method from Apple.